# matrix multiplication order PVM vs MVP in graphics programming

Tags: math, matrix, 3d

hi there I was wondering why most tutorials and programming code use MVP to describe the Model-View-Projection matrix. Instead of PVM which is the actual order of implementation in the code:

```
mat4 MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;
gl_Position = MVP * VertexInModelSpace;
```

seems much more understandable to me to write PVM instead of MVP.

Comment: It's described MVP intentionally. M first, since the matrix `M` is the first applied to the vector, then the `V` matrix, and finally the `P`. Matrix multiplication is associative, therefore the final vector equals `(P*(V*(M*vector)))`. The order of operations is from the inside, out.

Comment: @davin that's one way of thinking about it. The way you put it is very programmer friendly. But it does not mean the other way is less correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matrices don't actually have a fixed meaning, just relations between rows and columns. The meaning is freely definable by the developers. The MVP order follows from standard mathematical conventions. But since nothing says you can not define the vectors as columns instead of rows nothing precludes this ordering.

**Clarification:** Since changing notation transposes the meaning. Then following applies:

M<sub>mvp</sub><sup>T</sup> = M<sub>pvm</sub>

Due to the definition of matrix multiplication following rule kicks in:

(AB)<sup>T</sup> = B<sup>T</sup>A<sup>T</sup>

Since B can be recursively another matrix multiplication a infinite chain of these are possible. Which means essentially that you have swapped the multiplication order, by changing notation.

Its a bit like looking at the problem from the outside or the problem from the inside. In this case your thinking as a outside observer. Whereas the other way around one would observe the thing from the standpoint of the first operator in the chain. Personally I think the notation you use may be more intuitive for this specific task, the other is just way more common. Mainly due to the fact that all mathematics books I have ever seen use this convention, so blame the mathematicians.

So better stick with the more common way, makes things more generally understandable. For example: Nothing stops me from typing the answer in Finnish but the convention of stackoverflow is to answer in English, making answers more understandable to most users. Use the more common form since others may not grasp the difference, and this leads to errors.

Answer (score 0):

The other problem is that matrix multiplication is not necessarily commutative:

```
AB != BA
```

So it's a good idea to stick with the convention.

Comment: Ok, seems like my answer wasn't clear then. Its safe to say that space transforms are not commutative for moist parts. However this has nothing to do with commutation but rather if you transpose the vector then you transpose the matrix and for square matrices this just changes eh multiplication order to inverse order.

Comment: updated my answer to clarify things up a bit better in this light

Comment: Yes, I know how the transpose works.  "Moist" parts?  Oh, my.  We might need moderator attention.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the typo but by then the fix time of my comment was closed, I can kill it if it makes you any happier. But really the point he is asking why is it way ABCD not DCBA and the answer still stands. No reason really. We have just agreed that vectors are rows not columns. If you make the other agreement then its right because you transpose everything. Nothing to do with commutativity. Just a question of deciding on what to type. Nothing says that the matrices are the same, as they in fact are not. PS: I'm actually happy that you helped me understand what my answer was lacking.

Comment: I'm just teasing - your answer is quite correct, as is mine.  The proposed change is not possible WITHOUT the transpose, as you've made clear.  Vectors can be thought of as rows or columns; their mathematical definition as a first order tensor stands either way.

Comment: :) Yes. Its not actually a transpose per see; the notations have a transposed meaning. But they follow form typing in the values in certain order. So it's just a question of the natural order of how you want to type things. Because the matrix in situation here is most likely four vectors or 4 rows. If you write them in 4 columns it results in the transpose, even if that wasn't the intention. That's just how you reconciliate between the orders. Nothing also says that the order of columns/rows need to be fixed into x y z w order they can be in  w z y x order too, mathematics does not care.

Comment: I think the order does matter, because if you change it you have to swap rows in the transform.  You gave a good answer, joojaa.  I'd stop now if I were you.

Comment: Ok, I just found this is a interesting meta discussion about what mathematical things are :)